# Is there any way to make the screensaver stop, while Skype is in progress?

Tags: bash, scripts, skype, screensaver

I am trying to make the screensaver stop while Skype is in progress. I am trying to do this in a bash script (I would like to do it in Bash). The bash script is quite simple: I start Skype, and while Skype is running I would like the script to turn off the screensaver. When I close Skype, I want the screensaver to turn on. I would like to get the way I mentioned (bash script).

My script is as following:

```
##############
my_script.sh

#!/bin/bash
skype &
screensaver.sh &

PID=$(ps -opid= -C mousepad)
while [[ ( -d /proc/$PID ) && ( -z `grep zombie /proc/$PID/status` ) ]]; do
        sleep 1
done && killall screensaver.sh && xdotool mousemove 100 100

##############
screensaver.sh # It's a script to move the mouse every 300s

#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
    xdotool mousemove 000 000 &
    sleep 300
    xdotool mousemove 000 001 &
    sleep 300       
done
```

The script passes through the while clause without stopping while skype is running.
My knowledge about programming is limited, so I would appreciate a simple explanation.
Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command disables screen locking in Ubuntu:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

You could skip the second script and just do:

```
#!/bin/bash
skype &
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
{
    while pgrep -x skype >/dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
    gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
} &
```

*Edit:*

For Xubuntu there are four commands to disable screen locking:

```
gsettings set apps.light-locker light-locker-enabled false
gsettings set apps.light-locker late-locking false
gsettings set apps.light-locker lock-on-lid false
gsettings set apps.light-locker lock-on-suspend false
```

I don't know if all four are needed, but those are the ones which are used for the guest session.

Comment: thanks for the information. </br>
My problem is focused in the "while" statement. I guess I must not be explaining this clearly. I only want that the script (screensaver) is actived when Skype is running. At the moment I close Skype, the mentioned script has to close. So my idea is to use a "while" statement. The computer checks every second if the Skype's PID is in process. If Skype is in process, the script is ON, BUT at the moment Skype's PID is not in process, the script has to close (OFF). My doubt is about the "while" statement. I don't obtain the results I want. Thanks.

Comment: @jos: Ok, I edited the answer, but saw that you found another solution.

Comment: IT WORKS. However, the command 
 "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true"
does not work in my Xubuntu 14.04. After a while my screen is blank. But the "while" statement works perfectly.
Thank you.

Comment: @jos: You didn't tell us until now that you are on Xubuntu, where other commands apply. Let me know if you need those, or if you still made it work.

Comment: I didn't explain clearly enough in the past posts. My script works well, I think it will be smarter with the command to disable the screen locking for Xubuntu 14.04. If you know the solution, I appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jos: I stated the Xubuntu equivalents in the answer.

Comment: I've checked in my user session and I've had the following result in all commandas: "No such schema 'apps.light-locker". I suppose it is different the configuration of my user's session than the guest's session. Do you know where is my screensaver configuration?

Comment: @jos: Well, light-locker is the default screensaver in Xubuntu, if I understand it correctly, and that schema is included in the light-locker package. Did you manually replace it with some other screensaver?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I have been using Linux for 3 years and I have a lot of things to learn. Perhaps I did change the default screensaver, but it wasn't my intention.

Comment: @jos: Ok. Possibly you have xscreensaver. Anyway, I had a look at my Xubuntu installation, but failed to figure out which commands to use in Xubuntu. If I was you, I'd keep the working solution as is for now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution thanks to DopeGhoti: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342936/bash-how-to-make-a-process-works-while-skype-is-working

```
#!/bin/bash
skype &
skype_PID=$!

screensaver.sh &
process_PID=$!

wait $skype_PID
kill $process_PID
```

Thanks Gunnar for your help.